# How can I get value from Parameter Store?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-parameter-store

I'm looking for an implementation to retrieve values from Parameter Store using AWS SDK for PHP v2. While in v3, it's possible to retrieve values using getParameter, it seems that getParameter doesn't exist in v2. How did they retrieve values from Parameter Store in v2?

I want to know how to retrieve values from Parameter Store using AWS SDK for PHP v2.

Comment: As an option make a rest call without SDK https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetParameter.html.